# Python Popen - exporting log file - breaks ffmbc command

Tags: python, environment-variables, popen

I am compiling a command line for ffmbc which is being used by Popen. This all works until I add in a final line which exports out a report, then ffmbc refuses to run.

Here is the command which runs fine with Popen:

```
command = 'ffmbc.exe -i “my_file.mov” -acodec pcm_s16le -map_audio_channel 0:1:0:0:1:0 -map_audio_channel 0:1:0:0:1:1 -map 0:0 -timecode "00:00:00:00" -vcodec prores -profile hq -vtag apch -f mov -y “my_output_file.mov”'

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
self.process1 = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Now if I add this at the end of the command `2> "report_log.txt"` then the Popen command fails, (this runs fine in a command line window).

So here is the complete command which fails with Popen:

```
command = 'ffmbc.exe -i “my_file.mov” -acodec pcm_s16le -map_audio_channel 0:1:0:0:1:0 -map_audio_channel 0:1:0:0:1:1 -map 0:0 -timecode "00:00:00:00" -vcodec prores -profile hq -vtag apch -f mov -y “my_output_file.mov” 2> "report_log.txt"'

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
self.process1 = Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

If I run the above complete command in a command line window then it runs fine, but not with Popen. Not sure why.

Comment: you should probably remove the fancy quotes from the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the stderr output from `Popen` in the following way:

```
import subprocess

with open('logfile', 'w') as logfile:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'foo'], stderr=logfile)
```

For me this writes `cat: foo: No such file or directory` to the `logfile`.

Comment: Sorry, copy, paste error, I have now corrected this .

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

`2>` is a shell redirection. `Popen()` does *not* run the shell unless you ask. To redirect stderr to a file without the shell:

```
with open("report_log.txt", "wb", 0) as file:
    self.process = Popen(command, stderr=file)
```